# Overriding css in dynamically generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `bootstrap-select`, which adds `div` on top of `select`. In other terms, I define:

```
<select id="@Html.IdForModel()" 
    name="@Html.NameForModel()" 
    class="selectpicker form-control" 
    data-live-search="true"></select>
...

 var selectBox = $('#@Html.IdForModel()');
 selectBox.selectpicker()
```

But in the page with Developer Tools I see:

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control">
  <button .../>
  <div class="dropdown-menu open" .../>
  <select .../>
</div>
```

Now I need this outer div to be `"display:block"`, this fixes some layout problems I experience. But `btn-group` and `bootstrap-select` both apply `"display:block-inline"`.

I've tried:

- Defining my own style for `bootstrap-select` in separate css file
- Adding `!important` to my definition
- `selectBox.parent().addClass("select-parent-div");`, with my css having: `.select-parent-div{display: block !important}`

The only thing that has worked is `selectBox.parent().css("display", "block");` but I would really like to have my styles in css files. Why doesn't css apply and what can I do about that?

Comment: You need to check if the style that apply bootstrap i marked as !important in this case css will not take your style in consideration, I faced this problem before and the trick that is work is to create the same style with the same name of bootstrap in your page and change the properties as you like

Comment: @mbadeveloper It doesn't, but it is `less` - I'm a bit unfamiliar with it. The rule that is applied looks like this: `.bootstrap-select.btn-group {
  &:not(.input-group-btn),
  &[class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0;
  }`

Comment: @mbadeveloper Wow! Copying a part of less and modifying it has actually worked!. If you post this as an answer,  I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the style that apply bootstrap is marked as !important in this case css will not take your style in consideration.

I faced this problem before and the trick that is work is to create the same style with the same name of bootstrap in your page and change the properties as you like.